# How to know which method is not covered by Unit test?

Tags: 8, testing

I want to finish the Unit test for a contrib module and I want to know if there is a way to know the methods that don't have tests, so this way, I can identify the tests I need to implement.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Code coverage reports?

Comment: @Kevin yes something like this.

Comment: I mean, did you run the test suite / phpunit with code coverage reporting?

Comment: @Kevin I don't know how to do it, do you have any idea on how to generate this report?

Comment: https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.3/code-coverage-analysis.html
I am not sure if Drupal CI supports this.

Comment: Look at the PHPUnit xml file and the docs/args